# jQuery: selecting all members of a class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Following the instructions in the comments of the function below, I tried to select every member of the class 'piece,' divide it in half (using :even :odd selectors) and then add two different classes to them. But I'm getting an error message that that says there are 0 members of each class. Have I selected them incorrectly?

```
function setUpPieces() {
    //select all the divs with class 'piece'
    //add the 'light' class to half of them
    //add the 'dark' to the other half
    $('.piece:even').addClass('light');
    $('.piece:odd').addClass('dark');

}
```

Update:

These are the instructions

```
The jQuery selectors :even and :odd may be useful.

An example:

$('div:even')
selects half of the divs on the page: the first one (the one at index 0) and then every second div after it (the ones at indicies 2,4,6 ...)

$('div:odd')
selects the other half.
```

Comment: Are they in an even/odd order in the DOM, (siblings etc) ?

Comment: Please provide a jsFiddle demo.

Comment: @sparky672 it's from a codecademy.com exercise you can see here. http://www.codecademy.com/courses/jquery-checkers/0?curriculum_id=4fc3018f74258b0003001f0f#!/exercises/1

Comment: You could try something like `$('.piece').is(':even').addClass('light');`. What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/WduHE/4/ Works here.

Comment: @adeneo no, they are not in even/odd order on the DOM. the instructions (see updated OP) seem to imply that the pieces will be indexed in an array

Comment: @Michael - It should work with nested elements, but could give some strange results in some browsers, did you try just setting the same rules in CSS and see if that works, and you did of course wrap the code in document.ready and the usual stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When is the setUpPieces function running?  Make sure you're applying that after the document ready.  The code you have to add the classes look correct.  Here's a Fiddle showing it in action:

http://jsfiddle.net/DeGeb/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use :nth-child in order to select odd and even elements.

```
    $('.piece:nth-child(even)').addClass('light');
    $('.piece:nth-child(odd)').addClass('dark');
```

**Update:** Here's a working demo http://jsfiddle.net/Fy6FC/

Comment: Per the jQuery docs, :even and :odd will work fine (http://api.jquery.com/even-selector/).  It does say it will be faster if you select the full set of elements, then use .filter(':even') on the full set.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through all of .piece elements, it will be faster.

```
function setUpPieces() {
    //select all the divs with class 'piece'
    //add the 'light' class to half of them
    //add the 'dark' to the other half
    $('.piece').each(function(i) {
        $(this).addClass(i%2 === 0 ? "light" : "dark");
    });
}
```